# How to write lowpass filter for sampled signal in Python?

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, python

I have some signal that sampled each 1 ns (1e-9 sec) and have, let say, 1e4 points. I need to filter high frequencies from this signal. Let say I need to filter frequencies higher than 10 MHz. I want that for frequencies lower than cutoff frequency signal will be passed unchanged. It means gain of the filter will be 1 for frequencies lower than cutoff frequency. I would like to be able to specify filter order. I mean, first order filter have 20 db/decade slope (power roll off) after cutoff frequency, second order filter have 40 db/dec slope after cutoff frequency and so on. High performance of code is important.

Answer (score 19):

The frequency response for the filter designed using the *butter*
function is:

[image: Butterworth Filter Response]

But there is no reason to limit the filter to a constant monotonic
filter design.  If you desire a higher attenuation in the stopband
and steeper transition band, other options exist.  For more information
on specifying a filter using *iirdesing* see [this](http://bit.ly/JPS4Zs).  As shown by
the frequency response plots for the *butter* design the cutoff 
frequency (-3dB point) is far from the goal.  This can be alleviated
by down-sampling before filtering (the design
functions will have a difficult time with such a narrow filter, 2% of 
the bandwidth).  Lets look at filtering the original sample 
rate with the cutoff specified.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from scipy.signal import fir_filter_design as ffd
from scipy.signal import filter_design as ifd

# setup some of the required parameters
Fs = 1e9           # sample-rate defined in the question, down-sampled

# remez (fir) design arguements
Fpass = 10e6       # passband edge
Fstop = 11.1e6     # stopband edge, transition band 100kHz
Wp = Fpass/(Fs)    # pass normalized frequency
Ws = Fstop/(Fs)    # stop normalized frequency

# iirdesign agruements
Wip = (Fpass)/(Fs/2)
Wis = (Fstop+1e6)/(Fs/2)
Rp = 1             # passband ripple
As = 42            # stopband attenuation

# Create a FIR filter, the remez function takes a list of 
# "bands" and the amplitude for each band.
taps = 4096
br = ffd.remez(taps, [0, Wp, Ws, .5], [1,0], maxiter=10000) 

# The iirdesign takes passband, stopband, passband ripple, 
# and stop attenuation.
bc, ac = ifd.iirdesign(Wip, Wis, Rp, As, ftype='ellip')  
bb, ab = ifd.iirdesign(Wip, Wis, Rp, As, ftype='cheby2')
```

[image: Original Sample Rate Filters]

As mentioned, because we are trying to filter such a small percent
of the bandwidth the filter will not have a sharp cutoff.  In this
case, lowpass filter, we can reduce the bandwidth to get a better
looking filter.  The python/scipy.signal resample function can 
be used to reduce the bandwidth.

Note the resample function will perform filtering to prevent 
aliasing.  Prefiltering can also be perfomed (to reduce aliasing)
and in this case we could simply resample by 100 and be *done*, but
the question asked about creating filters.  For this example 
we will downsample by 25 and create a new filter

```
R = 25;            # how much to down sample by
Fsr = Fs/25.       # down-sampled sample rate
xs = signal.resample(x, len(x)/25.)
```

If we update the design parameters for the FIR filter the 
new response is.

```
# Down sampled version, create new filter and plot spectrum
R = 25.             # how much to down sample by
Fsr = Fs/R          # down-sampled sample rate
Fstop = 11.1e6      # modified stopband
Wp = Fpass/(Fsr)    # pass normalized frequency
Ws = Fstop/(Fsr)    # stop normalized frequency
taps = 256
br = ffd.remez(taps, [0, Wp, Ws, .5], [1,0], maxiter=10000)
```

[image: Downsampled Filter Response]

The filter operating on the downsampled data has a better
response.  Another benefit of using a FIR filter is that you 
will have linear phase response.

Comment: Thank you. How you create graph of signal spectrum?

Comment: Thanks so much for an excellent answer! I wonder if you could possibly explain how to apply an FIR filter based on the coefficients computed using Remez? I'm having trouble understanding what `filtfilt` wants for the `a` parameter.

Comment: Once you have the coefficients from a filter design,
(_b_ for FIR _b_ and _a_ for IIR) you can used a 
couple different functions to perform the filtering:
_lfilter_, _convolve_, _filtfilt_.  Typically all
these functions operate similar:

    y = filtfilt(b,a,x)

If you have a FIR filter simply set _a=1_, _x_ is the
input signal, _b_ is the FIR coefficients.  This 
[post](http://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/194.php) might help as well.

Answer (score 5):

Does this work?

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

fs = 1E9 # 1 ns -> 1 GHz
cutoff = 10E6 # 10 MHz
B, A = butter(1, cutoff / (fs / 2), btype='low') # 1st order Butterworth low-pass
filtered_signal = lfilter(B, A, signal, axis=0)
```

You're right, though, [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html) is not very complete.  It looks like `butter` is a wrapper for `iirfilter`, which [is better documented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iirfilter.html):

> N : int
>      The order of the filter.
>   Wn : array_like
>       A scalar or length-2 sequence giving the critical frequencies.

Most of this stuff is cloned from matlab, though, so you can look at [their documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/butter.html;jsessionid=6c3d0daeb1680606cfe3b566de0e) too:

> the normalized cutoff frequency Wn must be a number between 0 and 1, where 1 corresponds to the Nyquist frequency, π radians per sample.

**Update:**

I added [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html) for these functions. :)  [Github makes it easy.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/298)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your application is, but you may want to check out Gnuradio: http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr__firdes.html

The signal processing blocks are written in C++ (although the Gnuradio flow graphs are in Python), but you did say high performance is important.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having good results with this FIR filter. Notices it applies the filter twice, going "forward" and "reverse", so as to compensate for signal offset (`filtfilt` function didn't work, don't know why):

```
def firfilt(interval, freq, sampling_rate):
    nfreq = freq/(0.5*sampling_rate)
    taps =  sampling_rate + 1
    a = 1
    b = scipy.signal.firwin(taps, cutoff=nfreq)
    firstpass = scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, interval)
    secondpass = scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, firstpass[::-1])[::-1]
    return secondpass
```

A great resource to filter design and use, from where I took this code, and from where band-pass and hi-pass filter examples can be taken, is [THIS](http://mpastell.com/2010/01/18/fir-with-scipy/).

Comment: I don't believe there is much benefit forward and reverse filtering a FIR filter.  An IIR filter can benefit from forward/reverse (filtfilt) because you can get linear phase from a non-linear phase filter by reverse filtering.

Comment: @ChristopherFelton I just reverse in order to synchronize a RAW electromyographic signal with the smoothed version of itself. I know I could just shift the signal, but filtering twice ends up being less trouble. It is worth noticing that the second pass almost doesn't change the already filtered first pass... Thanks for noting!

Comment: Ahh, yes.  To remove the delay (group delay), good point.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have comment rights ...

@endolith: I use the same as you except using the **scipy.signal.filtfilt(B, A, x)** where **x** is the input vector to be filtered - e.g. **numpy.random.normal(size=(N))**.  **filtfilt** makes a forward and reverse pass of the signal.  For the sake of completeness (most being the same as @endolith):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sps

input = np.random.normal(size=(N)) # Random signal as example
bz, az = sps.butter(FiltOrder, Bandwidth/(SamplingFreq/2)) # Gives you lowpass Butterworth as default
output = sps.filtfilt(bz, az, input) # Makes forward/reverse filtering (linear phase filter)
```

**filtfilt** as also suggested by @heltonbiker requires arrays of coefficients I believe.  In case you need to perform bandpass filtering at complex baseband a more involved config is needed but this does not appear to be a problem here.